# I need a portable OS on USB that can save document changes to the USB

Tags: boot, usb

I am trying to help a charity that has workers in Nepal.
They have received a bunch of old laptops with out hard drives.
Is it possible to create a USB with Ubuntu as a bootable operating system and have documents save to the USB?

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

Google Search turned this up it appears the second part of your question
(document changes save-able)
is explained here

thanks for asking this because ive been wondering too!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use Puppy Linux. It has a LTS version based on Ubuntu 12.04. It is very small an fast (it is meant to be run from USB), you just have to check that you have all the applications you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's easy with Ubuntu, which actually has a tool installed by default to accomplish just that. It's name is `usb-creator-gtk` but the name is translated so if you just search for USB in the dash, you should be able to find it. If you're using another desktop such as with Lubuntu or Xubuntu, you'll find it in your system category of the application menu you're using.

In the window that appears, you'll just select the DVD image you wish to install from, such as ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso, then select the drive you wish to install to and choose the option to store changes. This space is limited to 4GB, so if you have a large memory stick and want to enable users to store more data, you may want to partition the USB device, adding a second file system that's mounted as /home. That can then be as large as the device can handle.

If it sounds complicated, it really isn't. And if you can live with the storage limitations in the GUI creator, it really is quite simple.

Answer (score -1):

Yes It is Possible but you need something bigger than a 8GB usb drive as ubuntu take 5GB at most with everything installed with it plus with some space so I would recommend something something above 16gb.

Comment: You can use Ubuntu live with 5.5GB including 4GB for persistence or only 1GB without persistence. Of course, if the memory stick is bigger, you can always add more filesystems to use as /home, for instance.